# java: Adding recursively to an xml

Tags: java

I need a help. how can i add content recursively to an xml file. i have a program which processes a file and send  'line information's. these line informations needs to be written to an XML file, like shown below. what i do now is I read each line info and then send it a fn which writes XML. I want to know if there is any way to Buffer the Document object and then keep keeping appending to that Document object when each new line comes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
- <Rev_1.28>
- <OP type="SAM">
  <SRC_LN_FROM>612612</SRC_LN_FROM> 
  <SRC_LN_TO>703703</SRC_LN_TO> 
  <NO_LINES>92</NO_LINES> 
  </OP>
- <OP type="MOV">
  <SRC_LN_FROM>6122</SRC_LN_FROM> 
  <SRC_LN_TO>7033</SRC_LN_TO> 
  <NO_LINES>9</NO_LINES> 
  </OP>
  </Rev_1.28>
```

Comment: I suggest [StAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOM parser to create use org.w3c.dom.Document object as shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/).

The data is stored in primary memory, so this approach is acceptable if the data to be written is relativley small.